# Is or could be "War Slaves" grammatically accepted?

Tags: grammaticality

The correct way to write it, if I ain't wrong, is "Slaves of War", but could be "War Slaves" correct too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically English speakers say **prisoners of war** (**POWs**).

Captives who are made slaves are usually simply called slaves, no matter how they became slaves.

But to answer your question directly, you can write **slaves of war** as **war slaves**.

Comment: "I'm a slave of cheesecake/cheesecake slave." - does that mean I can't resist cheesecake, or that I'm slaving away in the kitchen making cheesecake? I think that it's difficult to say whether "slaves of war" would be read the same as "war slave" without understanding more of the context.

Comment: It would mean you can't resist cheesecake, but you would say *I'm a slave **for** cheesecake.*

Comment: Curtis, I didn't make my point very clearly... "POWs" is not the same thing as "War Slaves". "Slave" has a very different connotation in English than "prisoner", so without understanding what the asker wants the phrase to mean to the people reading it, it's very difficult to say whether it's correct and whether both phrases mean the same thing.

Comment: True, but English speakers don't typically qualify slaves. It's usually just slaves. **Captives of war** would be a better, more common word choice.